# Dynamically decide the table name in execute SQL task for CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I want to know if this is possible to do in SSIS Execute SQL task. I want to check for existence of a table, and if it doesn't exist, create the table. I want to keep the table name in a variable so I can execute the task against different databases and be able to change the table name.

As an example I have this code:

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='Table1' and xtype='U')
    Create Table Table1(
        Col11 varchar(10) primary key,
        Col12 varchar(10)
    );
```

For flexibility I want to store the value Table1 in a variable and keep changing it to create different tables each time I run the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, This is possible.
Here is how I would do it:

- Build another variable for your `SqlStatement` from your TableName
  variable. Depending on your version of SSIS this can bedone in two
  ways:

  In SSIS 2008 you need to use [Script Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to do the string concatenations.

  In SSIS 2012 you can leverage the [Expression Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213137.aspx).
- You can use the `Exressions` tab in `Execute SQL Task` and add an
  expression for `SqlStatementSource` and point it to your Variable.
  the variable should be the complete statement.