# SSIS SQLStatement Variable incorrect Syntax near@P1

Tags: ssis

I have created a variable in SSIS

> Name: TableName>
>
> DatType: String>
>
> Value: tDeviceData_Probe

then I have created an Excute SQL Task

> Connection Type: OLE DB
>
> Added my connection
>
> SQL SourceType: Direct
>
> Input SQL Statement: truncate Table ?

I added the Parameter Mapping:

> Variable Name: User::TableName
>
> Direction: Input
>
> Data Type: NVARCHAR
>
> Parameter Name: 0
>
> Parameter Size: 50

when I know execute this I am getting following error:

> *[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "truncate Table ?" failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.".
> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
> property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
> connection not established correctly.*

when I change the ? in the SQLStatement with the Variable Value it is working as expected

Comment: You cannot use a parameter in place of a literal table name. Instead use an expression to build the full SQL string. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873674/can-i-use-an-expression-to-set-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-task

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use an Expression to set a variable in a "SQL Statement Task"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873674/can-i-use-an-expression-to-set-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-task)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically decide the table name in execute SQL task for CREATE TABLE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688912/dynamically-decide-the-table-name-in-execute-sql-task-for-create-table-statement)

Comment: give the query that you have write in SQL Task

Comment: the SQL Statement I use is: truncate Table ?